# Issue with looping an audio file

Tags: android, loops, audio, media-player, android-mediaplayer

How can i get the value of repetitions completed from `mp.setLooping(true)`. I can use `OnCompletionListener` to get number of repetitions, but it produces 1sec delay between looping, which is annoying in a music oriented app. `OnCompletionListener` looping is not smooth as`mp.setLooping(true)`.

Any suggestions ? Thank in advance.

Code with 1sec delay or gap between looping:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
MediaPlayer mp1;
Button play;
int maxCount=10,n=1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.soundfile);
    play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mpplay();
        }
    });

}
private void mpplay() {
    mp1.start();
    mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {        
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp1) {
            if (n <= maxCount) {
                mp1.start();
                n++;
                if (n >= maxCount) {
                    n = 1;
                    mp1.stop();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

```
MediaPlayer mp1;
double play_times = 10;
int sound_length;
Handler handler;
boolean sound_playing = false;
int times_played = 0;

public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
    handler = new Handler();
    mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soundfile);
    sound_length = mp1.getDuration();
    mpplay();

}
private void mpplay() {
    times_played = 0;
    mp1.setLooping(true);
    mp1.start();
    sound_playing = true;
    handler.postDelayed(loop_stopper, (int)(sound_length*(play_times-.5)));
    handler.postDelayed(counter, sound_length);

}
private Runnable loop_stopper = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        sound_playing = false;
        mp1.setLooping(false);
    }
};
private Runnable counter = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (sound_playing) {
            times_played++;
            handler.postDelayed(counter, sound_length);
        }
    }
};
```

---

handler.postDelayed(loop_stopper, (int)(sound_length*(play_times-.5)));

This line will stop the looping halfway through the last desired loop.  Since this just means it won't continue looping, the sound file will still be fully played on the last repeat.

Comment: The above code works thanks, but how can i get the number of completed repetition value with your code, so that i can update the counter value to the user with every repetition.

Comment: The same idea, use a runnable that is executed every 'sound_length' milliseconds which increments a counter.  It is semi-approximate, but it should be fine.  I will add this to my answer.

Comment: You change my entire app concept. Thank you sooooo much :-).

Comment: playing_sound not declared ?

Comment: sorry, typo, switch playing_sound to sound_playing